# Python 3.10 - module 'socket' has no attribute 'IPPROTO_MPTCP'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, mptcp, multipath

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html), the "IPPROTO_MPTCP" protocol has been added to Python3.10, but when I create a socket like this,

```
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_MPTCP)
```

I get this error

```
module 'socket' has no attribute 'IPPROTO_MPTCP'
```

What could I be doing wrong in this? Here's a screenshot.

[Here's a screenshot as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDWNk.png)

Comment: It looks like Python needs to be compiled with that option. For example `socket.IPPROTO_EGP` works and I can see that it [is defined here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1aa6be06c4cb7f04a340adb1c7b16b89803ef254/Modules/socketmodule.c#L296) but `IPPROTO_MPTCP` is not defined in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Boris Verkhovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3064538/boris-verkhovskiy) guessed, for now Python needs to be compiled with the `IPPROTO_MPTCP` option. You can see that by going to the [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/changelog.html#changelog), then opening the ticket, you can check the [diff](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b05b48dd7ab68bf0046356f2abd6d7fe3b5b3d77)

If you are on linux, please also check your kernel version (>= 5.6) and whether MPTCP is enabled (`sysctl net.mptcp.enabled`). Check [this checklist](https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp_net-next/wiki/#how-to-use-mptcp) for more details.